# Installing Microsoft Azure add-ons

Tags: azure, installation, add-on

There are many tutorials and pictures on how to install add-ons on Microsoft Azure, but I can't find an explanation on how to do it with the new interface:

[image: Microsoft Azure new interface]

I've spent most of my morning trying to find ot how to do it. The closest I found was the marketplace but the add-on composer (Proof that this add-on exists: https://www.siteextensions.net/packages/ComposerExtension/) isn't there.

How do you install add-ons in the new UI?

Edit: I might have misnamed what I'm looking for. In some tutorials it's called Web App Extensions and in some others it's called Site Extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage site extensions using the Kudu debug console. Using the default Azure URL, insert SCM between your site name and the rest of the URL like this:
https://[yoursitename].**scm**.azurewebsites.net

This will launch the Kudu console and you'll find a Site Extensions tab at the top of the page.